# Help identifying anime with a ghost girl who drinks coffee

Tags: story-identification, anime, ghost

What I remember of the ~20 minutes that I saw, there was a male student in a school uniform with a jacket who was at their school at night and was being chased around it by a ghost girl drinking coffee from a vending machine. Then he went down some stairs as someone started fighting the ghost (which is when parts of the school started exploding). Then he found himself in this bizarre other worldly forest where he was greeted by two little nymphs/fairy things (they looked like a chibi shoulder demon and shoulder angel), then he struck some sort of bargain and the demon one bit his thumb and drank some of his blood. Then he walked for a ways and found what I can only describe as a weirdly rendered Scarab from Halo (it had the same basic shape, color, and movement). Then he bought some Shikigami and placed them next to his bed, and as he slept the ghost came back and one of the Shikigami (which he was having a dream with) sacrificed itself to chase away the ghost by flying into its mouth. When he woke up he found it crumpled and torn on the floor.

I have been trying to find this anime for years, and for years it has been periodically knowing at the back of my mind.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you watch this?

Comment: I watched it on either Crunchy Roll or a third party site around 2016